# error toast in progressbar's thread android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, progress-bar

I try to run a progressbar with a button, (click on the button and send a variable to the thread and fill a progressbar up with it).
i have made this code to sent the variable to the thread, then update the progressbar number and finally send it to the thread to show a toast after the progressbar is completed, but when should show the toast up it didn't do it. code button:

```
testme.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Descanzando ok, descanzando ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int n = rnd.nextInt(120-1)+1;
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"el numero random es "+n,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            startProgress(v,n);});
```

thred and toast:

```
public void startProgress(View view, int a) {
    bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    bar.setProgress(0);
    new Thread(new Task(a)).start();
}

class Task implements Runnable {
    int num=0;
    public Task(int a){
        num=a;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i <= num; i++) {
            final int value = i;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            bar.setProgress(value);
            if(value==num){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Completado ok, completado!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what are you trying to do but Toast have to get the activity itself as the context (instead of passing getBaseContext()), otherwise it wont be shown.

By the way you should really consider working with Handler and using the postDelay function instead of all of this:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable, long)